# About Google Cloud IOT core connect to device

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I m beginner use google cloud platform. I current do my Final Year Project . I want ask about google cloud iot core. How device like temperature sensor connect to device registry?

Regards,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to create a Google Cloud Platform project. Go to http://cloud.google.com and click the Getting Started button and it will walk you through getting your first project up and running.

Next, you'll want to go [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/) and follow the Quickstart Guide and it will walk you through creating a virtual device (code only, no physical device) using Node.js. If you prefer to use Python, I have a very detailed walkthrough for using Raspberry Pi [here](https://github.com/GabeWeiss/IoT_Core_Quick_Starts).

In terms of getting the hardware part working, the easiest (in my opinion) is going to be Raspberry Pi and Node.js, and use the [johnny-five module](http://johnny-five.io/).

Comment: I use arduino, Then how about the virtual device source code?

Comment: The virtual device code is the Quickstart Guide I linked in the answer: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/